# Solr, qtime vs response time

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I've a solr query that has a qtime of 2-3 (milliseconds). The response time, however, is about 5 seconds.

- The response format is CSV, so the response is as minimal as possible
- Only returning 2 'columns'
- Solr version is 4.10.3
- Solr under in-built jetty
- Response size ~500kb

Obviously, the problem seems to be in sending the data from solr to my application but if the query time is 2 milliseconds and the response is only ~500kb, it shouldn't take 5 seconds.

Is there perhaps a jetty setting to increase a buffered amount? Or a solr setting somewhere?

EDIT (solrconfig.xml):

```
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>4.7</luceneMatchVersion>
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}"/>
  <dataDir>/etc/solr/default/solr/${solr.core.name}/data</dataDir>
  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">/etc/solr/default/solr/${solr.core.name}/data</str>
    </updateLog>
  </updateHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="omitHeader">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" startup="lazy" />
  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true" />
  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" startup="lazy" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/admin/" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers" />

  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- term vector -->
  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>
  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str> <!-- config for the admin interface -->
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- more like this -->
  <searchComponent name="mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisComponent" />
  <requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler" />

  <!-- config for the admin interface -->
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>solr</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

  <!-- caches -->
  <query>
    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>

    <!-- Query Result Cache -->
    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>

    <!-- Document Cache -->
    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>
  </query>
</config>
```

Cheers

Comment: why it shouldn't take 5 seconds to transmit 500 kb? May be your connection is slow? are you using SolrCloud?

Comment: The network is a lot faster than that. Transfers of other sizes, are much faster. Similarly, Increasing the amount of data (to ~1MB) is doubling the amount of data to be sent on the network but the response times are similar.

Comment: could you show your solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Done! I did manage to make this about 5x quicker with a much higher document cache but it still seems quite slow to write the response if there's any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the 5 seconds is spent on the server? If you're not doing so already, one useful test would be to fire the query from the Solr Admin Interface and use a debugger (such as firebug) to determine how much network time is spent waiting and receiving.

In the past I have also had some issues with proxying, if you are using that, although that resulted in a failure to respond rather than a delay.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely on the server (have verified using similar methods you've suggested). Throwing some more debugging around it, I THINK the time is spent in the ResponseWriter.write method of SOLR. I wonder if there's any way to speed this up, changing buffer sizes, etc?